# Disallowing login for "inactive" users in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I set up my app's authentication system based on the [Symfony2 security documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html).

Each one of my users has an `active` flag. I don't want users whose `active` = false to be able to log in.

I don't really understand where the logic is that says whether or not a user is allowed to log in, so I'm somewhat at a loss as to how to accomplish this. Can someone please steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make your `User` class implement [`AdvancedUserInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.0/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/AdvancedUserInterface.php) — it has the `isEnabled()` method specifically for that purpose.

Comment: I did that and I implemented the `isEnabled()` method on my `User` class and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, implement `isEnabled()` on the `User` class in whatever way makes sense for your app.